# Android Service, do we have to use startService or BindService?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am developping a MusicPlayer app, and I use a local Service to be make the MediaPlayer run in the background. It seems that we can either send intent to start a Service or bind a Service. I understand the point of for startService, we leave it running and send intent to stopService, and for bindService, we get back a IBinder to communicate with the service. However, I'm wondering what's the point of doing this? Do we have to send intents to make it work?
If I just retrieve an static instance of Service, and directly call its methods, I can also implement both start it and communicate with it.

I found an example of not using startService nor bindService, but it works well as a simple MusicPlayer.

The fragment calls Service: 
https://github.com/zacharytamas/spotify-sampler/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zacharytamas/spotifysampler/ui/PlayerFragment.java

The Service class:
https://github.com/zacharytamas/spotify-sampler/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zacharytamas/spotifysampler/services/PlayerService.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I'm wondering what's the point of doing this?

To have the service be running, to tell the OS "hey, we are doing work here on behalf of the user, please let my process live a bit longer".

This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes).

> Do we have to send intents to make it work?

Yes.

> If I just retrieve an static instance of Service, and directly call its methods, I can also implement both start it and communicate with it.

Then it is merely a Java object, and there is no point in inheriting from `Service`. Also, it means that your process will live for less time when your UI is not in the foreground.

> I found an example of not using startService nor bindService, but it works well as a simple MusicPlayer.

The service is started, via `startService()`, [in `ArtistSearchActivity`](https://github.com/zacharytamas/spotify-sampler/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zacharytamas/spotifysampler/ui/ArtistSearchActivity.java). Until this is done, the service does not exist, and the singleton will be `null`.

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice that startService(). But this implementation is still quite different, it uses startService(), but still communicates with the service by registering custom events, can I say that this is another form of IBinder, like a custom EventBus implementation?

Comment: @dengn: "still communicates with the service by registering custom events" -- I do not see this, sorry. "can I say that this is another form of IBinder" -- no. It is merely an implementation of the singleton pattern. Also, please do not assume that code that happens to be on GitHub is necessarily production-grade code. In this case, the developer starts a service and never stops it. This violates a rule with services: [only have them running when they are actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

Answer (score 0):

startService is used when you don't need to communicate with the service.
BindService is used when yout need to communicate with it.

In your app, I think you will communicate with the service (for example, if you have an activity where you choose the song, your will send data to the service to say: "this is the song which you have to play now") and I think you will need BindService instead startService.

I hope this will help you :D